# Firefox Portable : "Another instance [...] is already running" but taskkill says there is no running instance

Tags: windows, firefox, task-manager, tasks

I wanted to change the folder from which I run FireFoxPortable, but now I get this when trying to open Firefox :

[image]

"Another instance of Firefox is already running."

But when I run taskkill :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>taskkill /F /FI "imagename eq firefox*"
ERROR: The process with PID 14148 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
```

As well in the task manager, under Processes, right-click on Firefox > End task : does seemingly nothing. And from the tab Details :  right-click on firefox.exe > End Task gives me this :

[image]

What sense does this all make ? How can I run Firefox again ?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the machine?

Comment: Yes. This has disappointingly worked.